# search data in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

i'm using vb.net and sql as my db
why my db could not display of my search data ?
my date format that store in db like this = **`MM/DD/YYYY`**

```
Private Function GetDate(ByVal strDev As String, ByVal strDate As String) As DataSet
Dim connectionString As String = "server='abc'; user id='abc'; password='abc'; Database='abc'"
Dim sqlConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Time_stamp, BB_ID, Status FROM rawdata WHERE (BB_ID = '" & strDev & "') AND (Time_stamp = '5/1/2011')"
Dim sqlCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@strDev", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char).Value = strDev
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@strDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char).Value = strDate
Dim dataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
Return dataSet
End Function
```

Comment: You're adding parameters to your `SqlCommand`, but the parameters aren't in your command itself?

Comment: Your `queryString` doesn't have the parameters @strDev and @strDate which you have added to sqlCommand.Parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Time_stamp, BB_ID, Status FROM rawdata WHERE (BB_ID = '" & strDev & "') AND (Time_stamp = '5/1/2011')"
```

to

```
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Time_stamp, BB_ID, Status FROM rawdata WHERE BB_ID = @strDev AND Time_stamp = @strDate"
```